# change height in tailwind height is zero(h-0) how chanege it to height 150px

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

how can i change height[h-0] to 150px using javascript in tailwind

```
 <div  class="h-0">hello world</div>
```

javascript code is like this adding active using toggle[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05mpT.png)

```
  <script>
        const accordion = document.getElementsByClassName('faq_info');

        for (let i = 0; i < accordion.length; i++) {
            accordion[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
               this.classList.toggle('active');
              
            })            
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Toggle `h-0` and `h-[150px]` classes on click.

```js
const accordion = document.getElementsByClassName('faq_info');

for (let i = 0; i < accordion.length; i++) {
  accordion[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('h-0');
    this.classList.toggle('h-[150px]');
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<button class="faq_info h-0 bg-red-300 w-20">Open</button>
```